# how to fill a cell on clicking the grid on canvas in html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to fill a grid cell on clicking on the particular cell.Here is my code:

```
 function drawBox()
    {   
        for (var row = 0; row < 14; row ++)
        {
            for (var column = 0; column < 13; column ++)
            {
                var x = column * 40;
                var y = row * 40;
                context.beginPath();
                context.rect(x, y, 40, 40);
                context.fillStyle = "white";
                context.fill();
                context.lineWidth = 3;
                context.strokeStyle = 'black';
                context.stroke();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[I've got a working sample here.](http://jsbin.com/aralik/2) [Code](http://jsbin.com/aralik/2/edit):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    c = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    boxSize = 40,
    boxes = Math.floor(600 / boxSize);
canvas.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', handleClick);

function drawBox() {
  c.beginPath();
  c.fillStyle = "white";
  c.lineWidth = 3;
  c.strokeStyle = 'black';
  for (var row = 0; row < boxes; row++) {
    for (var column = 0; column < boxes; column++) {
      var x = column * boxSize;
      var y = row * boxSize;
      c.rect(x, y, boxSize, boxSize);
      c.fill();
      c.stroke();
    }
  }
  c.closePath();
}

function handleClick(e) {
  c.fillStyle = "black";

  c.fillRect(Math.floor(e.offsetX / boxSize) * boxSize,
    Math.floor(e.offsetY / boxSize) * boxSize,
    boxSize, boxSize);
}

drawBox();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600px" height="600px"></canvas>
```

I edited the `drawBox()` function a bit to increase efficiency, also.

`e.offsetX` is the mouse coordinate, devide by `40`, then `Math.floor()` this to get the cell number, then multiply by `40` to get the starting coordinate of the cell.

Comment: offsetX and offsetY should be changed to clientX and clientY respectively. client definitely works in Firefox 37 and Chromium, but offset only works in Chromium.